# System tray notification via PHP

Tags: php, notifications, system-tray

I would like to create a simple notification icon that would display a number in the users system tray.

The application only needs to allow the input of an API key that it would use to fetch information from the server. So, for example:

http://www.example.com/api.php?key=dfg45tgyy67h

The PHP file will return two values, a number, and a URL. The number should appear in the system tray, and clicking on it should take you to the URL. The application should update the information at a specified interval, which can be hard-coded into the application.

I really have no idea how to do this, but can pick up things like this pretty quickly. So I would like to know some ways to accomplish this, or what the easiest method to use would be.

**EDIT** When I said PHP what I meant was that on the server it would be a PHP file serving up the information to the application. I didn't plan on creating the client application in PHP.

Comment: You're better off creating a client-side application in another language such as C/C#/C++/Java and having it access the PHP script on your server.  If you're trying to keep your development life simple and system tray is the only native interaction you need, you may want to Java because of its cross-platform abilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cross-platform language and widget toolkit with both browser launching and system tray capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with PHP as it has no way of interacting with a user's computer and and that includes the system tray. You'll need to write something that will run on their computer and then polls your PHP script for this information.

Comment: You *could* do it with PHP, you just can't do it with *server-side* PHP.

Comment: I have updated my question. The plan was to use PHP on the server, but not for the client application.

Comment: Since it doesn't really matter what language produces the site (it makes literally zero difference to your client side app), you should remove the tags and references to PHP.

Comment: Wouldn't it make some difference, since the app will have to request a PHP file to get the data that it needs?